# Simple password verification function not working

Tags: php, mysql

This is it:

```
function password_matches($username, $password){
    //precon: user_exists($username)
    $u = $GLOBALS['conn']->real_escape_string($username);
    $q = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$u'";
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $q);
    $result2 = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    return ($result2 == $password);
}
```

If you think this should work just tell me, I know my problems could be coming form somewhere else outside this function but I think that's less likely.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['conn']`??...please no!!

Comment: Plaintext passwords??...please no!!

Comment: I'm truly a beginner like the tilte says so I welcome any type of tips thanks a lot. Like the title used to say rather, I guess an admin edited the tilte.

Comment: Start with learning what is debug and debugging.

Comment: You should use PHP's `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions.

Comment: Read the documentation of `mysqli_fetch_field`. It doesn't return the result of the query, it returns metadata.

Comment: `real_escape_string` please no!! use prepared statements to protect against SQL injections. read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Yes I think I know what debugging is thanks u_mulder. Thanks Barmar I'll read about those.

Comment: Your code is also vulnerable to query injection, but I assume you're just trying to learn how this works and not actually deploying this code :) imagine what happens when the user uses the password 'OR 1==1'

Comment: `$result2` is not the actual value. You should read the docs about whar you are actually fetching. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php

Comment: Wow haha yeah, I got what you mean, but yes, I haven't started learning about security, I'm just strying to make the register/login work. Thanks Rens van der Heijden.

Comment: Yes Qirel, that seems to be the problem, I'll read it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

While there are lots of problems with the way you're doing this, you also just don't know how to use the `mysqli` functions properly, so I'll write an answer related to that, since you'll need to know it for other tasks.

`mysqli_fetch_field` returns metadata about the fields in the result, not the values. To get the actual data, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
return $row['password'] == $password;
```